# Multiple JS "ReplaceStrings" One is not working

Tags: javascript, replace

I have a slight understanding of this works, however, not enough to understand what's going on here. I believe it's creating a conflict and rendering one useless.

I'm trying to replace {{aff_id}} with a URL parameter.

This is in ClickFunnels FYI and it's being used in a email submit form.

Here is the code:

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var replaceString = "organic";
var replaceString2 = "null";
var urlTerm2 = getURLParameter("aff_id");
var urlTerm = getURLParameter("tid");
if (urlTerm.trim().length > 0 && urlTerm != "null") {
replaceString = decodeURIComponent(urlTerm).replace(/\+/g,' ');
}
$("body").html($("body").html().replace(/\{\{tid\}\}/g,replaceString));
if (urlTerm2.trim().length > 0 && urlTerm2 != "null") {
replaceString2 = decodeURIComponent(urlTerm2).replace(/\+/g,' ');
}
$("body").html($("body").html().replace(/\{\{aff_id\}\}/g,replaceString2));
});
</script>
```

I'm sure this is something super simple that I'm missing. NAy help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Thank you.

Comment: The second one will never do anything because body does not contain aff_id anymore

Comment: You need to decide which parameters you want to use in code before doing the replace, like that first if block

Comment: Updated the above code. Is this a better approach?

Comment: I just noticed that you are using two template strings, `{{tid}}` and `{{aff_id}}`, not just one. Sorry, I was reading the code on my phone. In this case your original code was OK.